# Drawing curved pipes with thickness and specified edge lengths in geometry nodes

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

Drawing curved pipes with thickness and specified edge lengths in geometry nodes

I can draw an outline of a pipe curve extruding vertices using **specified** values in modeling, but how can I do this in Geometry nodes.

Example: Pipe outline wanted

[image: img1]

The goal is to create a pipe with a thickness and adjustable edge lengths and angles that can be changed using geometry nodes.

[image: img2]

I was trying to use Curve Line and Set Position node but getting things to turn
the way I want didn't work out.

[image: img3]

PS: This will be 3D printed so that is why thickness is needed.

Comment: maybe i have too less coffee...but i don't understand what you wanna achieve...

Comment: I want to draw the shape shown in the outline image above in geometry nodes and have the ability to change the edge lengths.  But with a smooth pipe like transition for the curves.

Comment: so the shape is "fixed"? you just wanna change the length?

Comment: Yes the shape will be fixed I just want to change the length of each of the edges in GN and have smooth curving angles between the edges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you want to manually control every individual point I guess you could use something like the setup below, where a custom node group extrudes and offsets the top vertex created by the previous one, basically mimicking what you do in edit mode. Then convert that into a curve, turn it into a *Bezier* type so you can fillet the corners with a `Fillet Curve` with fewer control points (you could leave it as is and use the *Poly* mode, but then you're not taking advantage of the curve handles to create the fillet).

After that comes the usual maintenance—sweep a profile with `Curve to Mesh`, *Solidify* the result for thickness (custom `Extrude Mesh` group that keeps the original face), join the original geometry (just a single vertex) at the top of a `Join Geometry` node so auto-smooth works, if you want.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

although i am pretty sure you won't be very happy with it, but i think this will nearly always a pretty tedious way like this:

[image]

and then you have to calculate the angles/positions for your segments yourself. Of course you can use some node groups, who maybe can simplify the node tree a bit e.g. a node group which calculates point B from Point A for a giveN angle and length. But there is no "automated" way to do this AFAIK.